# Tensorflow Keras composite Model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I want to make a Model composed of other models which supports various training strategies. The main goals are:

- One model for input that has a specified `input_shape`, a few layers, and a single output layer
- Then *N* additional models all connected to the input model
- An additional Model which composes the above smaller models into one large multi-output Model

I could of course just build this as one large model but I have a specific bunch of training experiments I would like my composite model to support:

- Train the entire network together
- Train *1* to *N* outputs

  - Only effecting certain paths but propagating changes all the way through the input model
  - Support training the sub models on their own (which is why I have been thinking to build this as a composite of other models vs. one large one)

In pseudocode:

```
def build_model_a(input_layer):
    ... build model a using input_layer arg as input...
    model = Model(inputs=input_layer,
                  outputs=output_layer)
    model.compile(...)
    return model




input_model = build_input_model(args)
model_a = build_model_a(input_model.output)
model_b = build_model_b(input_model.output)

composite_model = Model(inputs=input_model.input,
                        outputs=[model_a.output,
                                 model_b.output])

# train from input_model through model_a but don't change model_b weights
model_b.trainable = False
composite_model.fit(...)

# train from input_model through model_b but don't change model_a weights
model_a.trainable = False
model_b.trainable = True
composite_model.fit(...)

# train from input_model through model_a but don't change model_b weights
model_b.trainable = True
model_a.trainable = True
composite_model.fit(...)

# Train just input_model
input_model.fit(...)

# Eval through entire model
composite_model.predict(xs)
```

That is my current approach which leads to an error with:

```
AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute '_name'
```

This makes me think I am not going about this correctly so I'm hoping for other advice or references. I'm fairly confident that this can be done with Keras functional API but am struggling to get it right.

I'm also not clear, if using this approach with `trainable = False`, is allowed. Based on the warnings from the fit run I need to re-compile these models after changing the trainable flag...

Answer (score 1):

At least for the first part of the question, you can use models as layers using the functional api, not using their inputs,outputs. Something like this:

```
# creation of a model
def build_model_a():
    ... build model create your own input...
    input_layer = Input(shape=i_shape)
    model = Model(inputs=input_layer,
                  outputs=output_layer)
    model.compile(...)
    return model

# model creations
input_model = build_input_model(args)
model_a = build_model_a()
model_b = build_model_b()

#connect models
input_layer = Input(shape=i_shape)
middle = input_model(input_layer)
out_a = model_a(middle )
out_b = model_b(middle )

composite_model = Model(inputs=input_layer ,
                        outputs=[out_a ,
                                 out_b ])
```

Maybe someone can complete the answer or you will be able to test yourself